# Update specific value in structure

Tags: json, swift, structure, codable

I can't seem to find out how to update a specific value in a structure in Swift 4. I have this structure:

```
struct Export: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let exportType: String
}
```

It is filled with values I got from a JSON.
I was using JSONDecoder

```
self.Exp = try JSONDecoder().decode([Export].self, from: data!)
```

Now I'm receiving a new JSON only containing an id.
I want to update the id of this structure with the new value.
The JSON sends a response like that :

```
{
    "id": "70CD044D290945BF82F13C13B183F669"
}
```

So even when I try to save it in a separate structure I get this error

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], 
debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", 
underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))
```

I tried to look for solutions before posting but I couldn't find any I'm pretty new to JSON handling and Swift...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the JSON part aside, you won't be able to update `id` in `Export`, since it is a `let` constant. You may want to change it to `var`.

If I understand correctly, you are receiving a JSON response with **only** an id. You don't create an `Export` struct out of it. You would need to process this JSON response separately to grab the id you are looking for. Like this:

```
import Foundation

let jsonText = """
{"id": "70CD044D290945BF82F13C13B183F669"}
"""

struct IdResponse: Codable {
    let id: String
}

let idResponse: IdResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(IdResponse.self, from: jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

And finally, update your `Export` struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Export: Decodable {
    var id: String
    let name: String
    let exportType: String
}

// Build export object
var export: Export = Export(id: "1", name: "Name", exportType: "TypeA")

// Grab JSON response from somewhere, which contains an updated id
let idResponse: IdResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(IdResponse.self, from: jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!)

// Update the object
export.id = idResponse.id
```

Comment: Additional note: The `try!` and `.data()!` are dangerous operations and should be properly handled. The `try` statement should handle error(s) thrown, and the forced-unwrapping of `.data()!` should be checked for `nil`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works when I do it your way! I'm still confused about the JSON... When I put it directly in my code like you did it's fine. But it doesn't work with the JSON I receive it's still saying its not a valid JSON, any idea of how I could format the JSON I receive into a string like yours? (with your additional double quotes ? without them it just won't work)

Comment: Sorry but we would need more details on the service that is providing the response, and your code that reads it and decodes it.

Comment: Nvm I found out what the problem was I was missing this line in my code: 
`request.setValue(" application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")`
and then I had to change the Id structure to add CodingKeys, everything works fine now! Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

**First,** of all your JSON is not in correct format.

**Secondly,** after you will receive correct JSON, for `self.Exp` you are getting array, but for your `idDict` you have only one dictionary object.

So, Keep those property `optional`, which are not necessary to appear in JSON. In your case it would be `name` and `exportType` as:

```
struct Export: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String?
    var exportType: String?
}
```

It can be used for `self.Exp` as:

```
self.Exp = try JSONDecoder().decode([Export].self, from: data!)
```

and for `idDict` as:,

```
idDict = try JSONDecoder().decode(Export.self, from: data!)
```